# React Native EXPO Apple upload fail

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I created the app through Expo.
I uploaded the ipa through the Application Loader, and it was rejected as the message below.
What is the problem?

> This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for
>   /Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle is missing or could
>   not be read.
>
> Invalid Bundle - The bundle at
>   ‘/Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle’ does not contain a
>   bundle executable.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and my app doesn't use React Native EXPO. I think there is an issue with AppStoreConnect at the moment. This is not related to Expo. It may be a general issue. I tried uploading the bundle many times. The same exact app yesterday was accepted just fine, and today I have this problem. I changed no code at all, so this is 100% an issue on the Apple side.

Comment: Same issues. I think this was a policy change as of 24 hrs. Looking into what's wrong - does this happen across all Expo builds? I do have a dependency of react-native-fbsdk

Comment: Also have the same issue, two separate accounts. I uploaded a build this morning and it was ok. Let's wait and see. Native app btw, just using Facebook frameworks

Comment: I could resolve the issue by renaming FacebookSDKStrings.bundle to FacebookSDKStrings located in "Pods/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/Resources/"

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2077613562276009/ Facebook has an open bug ticket related to it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is in the AppStoreConnect, as @Axy said, yesterday upload was fine, and I try to do today, I receive same error related Facebook bundle, nothing I've changed in my end,

It is an Apple related issue.

Update: Issue has been resolved, I able to upload my app successfully to the AppStoreConnect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolved this issue by resetting pods.

1. Remove Pods folder.
2. `pod cache clear --all`
3. `pod install`
4. Create archive then upload it.

Comment: Builds are now being accepted without any changes. It looks like clearing your cocoapod cache was a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue from early morning. For a quick fix, on your Xcode workspace check the below path,

> Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/Resources

you will find a `FacebookSDKStrings.bundle`, remove the extension bundle it will be changed to folder structure `FacebookSDKStrings`. Now clean the build and Archive it will be uploaded successfully.

Comment: Those strings are used for internationalization. Does this change affect their use in any production apps?