# Invalid iOS Bundle

Tags: ios, facebook, bundle, fbsdk

> **This bundle is invalid** - The Info.plist file for /Payload/xxx.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle
>   is missing or could not be read.
>
> **Invalid Bundle** - The bundle at '/Payload/xxx.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle'
>   does not contain a bundle executable.

I'm at the wits end now. I've spent over 6 hours trying to figure this one out. I've also manually downloaded the FB SDK for my Swift app and try to point the Framework to the FBSDKCoreKit.framework in the Downloaded package.

Deleted my derived date and cleaned everything before trying to upload again. Still can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i just got this error message too after uploading into testflight today

Comment: please do check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798216/react-native-expo-apple-upload-fail

Comment: I got this error message too, it worked fine before, I didn't change anything in project settings or info.plist. just fixed some UI issues. weird.
Mine is not react native. it's a swfit 4 project.

Comment: This is open issue at Facebook Dev https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2077613562276009/

Comment: Issue has been resolved by Apple, now I able to upload my app to AppStoreConnect

Answer (score 2):

I got a same issue.

**This bundle is invalid - The Info.plist file for /Payload/Treats.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle is missing or could not be read.
Invalid Bundle - The bundle at '/Payload/Treats.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable.**

I could resolve the issue by renaming FacebookSDKStrings.bundle to FacebookSDKStrings located in "Pods/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/Resources/"

Comment: I'm making an app with EXPO. Do you know how to deal with EXPO?

Comment: I extracted, changed the filename in my Expo app, and re-uploaded but it did not help.

Comment: I have a native build and faced the same issue. This solution actually worked for me ....

Comment: This is no longer needed. Apple fixed the issue on their side.

Comment: This answer should be deleted. Apple/Facebook fixed this issue.